# Como mudar gráfico ao mudar data

Tags: c#, mvc

Primeiramente peço desculpas pelo meu desconhecimento de alguns conceitos, sou novo na área. Comecei recentemente em uma empresa no qual tenho o seguinte problema:

Tenho um `Datepicker` e ao selecionar uma data, preciso que o gráfico seja alterado conforme a data selecionada.

Já implementei alguns campos onde as estatísticas mudam conforme a data escolhida, utilizando `POST`. Tentei fazer algo similar retornando uma `WebImage` ou um Chart pelo controller porém o gráfico aparece em branco.

View:

```
img id="graf" src="@Url.Action("DrawChartMaq", new { id = Model.maq_id })"

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#periodo").datepicker({

        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

        nextText: 'Próximo',

        prevText: 'Anterior',

        onClose: function (selectedDate){

            $("#jquery").html(selectedDate);

            var url = "/Efc_Maquina/SetarDatePicker";

            var xurl = "/Efc_Maquina/DrawNewChart";

            var dia = selectedDate;

            var id = @Model.maq_id;

            $.post(url, { Datatexto: dia, choose: 1, id: id}, function(data) {
                $("#estat1").html(data);
            })

            $.post(url, { Datatexto: dia, choose: 2, id: id}, function(data) {
                $("#estat2").html(data);
            })

            $.post(xurl, { Datatexto: dia, id: id }, function(image){
                $("#graf").attr('src', image);
            })
```

Controller:

```
public Chart DrawNewChart(string Datatexto, int? id)
{

    DateTime data = DateTime.Parse(Datatexto);

    ArrayList xvalue = new ArrayList(); // valores puxados do BD
    ArrayList yvalue = new ArrayList(); // valores puxados do BD           

    return new Chart(width: 800, height: 400)
       .SetXAxis("", 9, 18)
       .SetYAxis("", 0, 100)
       .AddSeries("Defa", chartType: "Column", xValue: xvalue, yValues: yvalue)
       .Write("bmp");

}
```

Agradeço desde já.

...Como tinha dito sou novo na área e provavelmente não utilizei as ferramentas corretamente e não tenho certeza se a solução que achei é a mais correta porém vou compartilhar.
Não tinha necessidade de mudar as estatísticas e gráfico sem atualizar a página, então resolvi o meu problema redirecionando para a mesma Action Details em que eu estava, passando os parâmetros necessários para gerar estatísticas e gráfico com a data selecionada.
Não sei se estou correto mas acredito que para redirecionar quando selecionada a data, não seria necessário estar dentro do POST, vou procurar me informar sobre isso.

```
$.post("/Controller/View", { id: id, Datatexto: dia }, function (image) {
                        window.location.href = "/Controller/View/" + id + "?Datatexto=" + dia;})
```

Comment: Qual o formato de retorno do Controller? É um html mesmo? Acredito que talvez o que deseje seja algo neste sentido: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: No Controller faço o gráfico com as informações do banco de dados utlizando o Helper Chart :  img id="graf" src="@Url.Action("DrawChartMaq", new { id = Model.maq_id })"  . Até aí tudo bem, ele aparece como desejo na View em html. Porém preciso que ele mude dinamicamente conforme a data selecionada. Para isso tentei implementar uma nova função no Controller retornando um Chart ou WebImage. O gráfico muda porém aparece uma nova imagem em branco. @rodrigorf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pesquisa sobre o Ajax do JQuery eu uso muito para fazer isso.
E tenta mudar o evento do date picker para onSelect
No seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
$.ajax({
url: '/Efc_Maquina/DrawNewChart',
type: 'POST',
datatype: 'application/text',
data: { Datatexto: dia, id: id }, //Parametros
success: function (data) {
    //Aqui vc trabalhao o retorno do servidor em caso de sucesso

    //Acredito q o retorno dessa chart seja o endereço de uma imagem certo?
     $("#graf").attr('src', data);
    },
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
   //Aqui vc trata algum erro retornado do servidor
},
complete: function (data) {
//Aqui vc executaria alguma ação ao finalizar esse processo
}
});
}
```

Testei algum com um método ficticio me retornando um diretorio de imagem e funcionou perfeitamente.. Atualiza a imagem...

Agr se no caso esse chart for algum outro objeto.. Como Canvas teria de usar outra tag ao invés de img.